# Cassandra : isolated workloads

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I have three workloads.

1. DATACENTER1 sharing data by rest services - streaming ingest
2. DATACENTER2 load bulk - analysis
3. DATACENTER3 research

I want to isolated workloads, i am going to create one datacenter foreach workloads.
The objective of the operation is to prevent a heavy process from consuming all the resources and gurantee hight availablity data.

Is anyone already trying this ?

During a loadbulk on datacenter2, is data availability good on datacenter1 ?

Comment: Will your datacenters sync the data?

Comment: YES, i will sync data all datacenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that workload won't cause disruption of load across datacenter. How it works is as follows:

Conceptually when you create a Keyspace, Cassandra creates a Virtual Data Center (VDC). Nodes with similar workloads must be assigned to same VDC. Segregating workload will ensure that only (exactly) one workload is ever executed at a VDC. As long as you follow this pattern, it works.

Data sync needs to be monitored under load on busy nodes but thats a normal concern on any Cassandra deployment.

Datastax Enterprise also support this model as can be seen from:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployWkLdSep.html#deployWkLdSep__srchWkLdSegreg